# How to pass in a null character in a command line argument in C?

Tags: c, command-line, escaping

I would still like to know how to pass in a null character as a command line argument, maybe so that a single string can be passed in as an argument in the form:

> "to\0be\0or\0not\0to\0be\0"

And then parse it.
However the program would treat this string as:

> "to\\0be\\0or\\0not\\0to\\0be\\0"

How can I work around this? Is there any way?

Comment: It would help to know which OS (and shell, if your OS has multiple shells) you're targeting, since this behavior would be external to your program.

Comment: Of course, sorry.
bash shell under Linux.

Comment: What's so problematic about using another character to separate arguments instead of `0x00`? Why not use the standard space (`0x20`) or some other character instead (maybe even `0x01`)?

Answer (score 22):

You cannot.

The C program receives arguments as zero-terminated strings. Such a string cannot contain a null character, by definition.

If you want to pass a null character, then you must somewhat encode it with some syntax, and your C program must then decode it by interpreting that syntax.

Comment: When I execute `./prog $(python -c "print 'aa\x00bb'")` in Bash on Ubuntu, the C program gets the argument as `aabb`, meaning instead of terminating the string at the null byte, it ignored it. Does this make any sense to you?

Comment: Bash still resides between Python and the C program; Bash gathered the bytes produces by the Python invocation (including the null byte) and built an argument string for the C program out of these bytes. Apparently Bash handles null bytes specially, by skipping them instead of letting them truncate the string.

Comment: `$ echo $(python -c "print 'aa\x00bb'")` issues a warning to the bash tty: `bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`.

Comment: When zsh executes `echo $(python3 -c "print('aa\x00bb')")`, you get `aa bb` (with the space character 0x20).  With bash, you get `aabb`, with no space.

Answer (score 6):

C strings are null-terminated, so passing strings containing NUL characters is not possible in C. :-P

Now, if you just wanted a way to convert `\0` (in the user input, i.e., `"\\0"` as a C string) into actual NUL characters, that's another matter. In that case, your program just needs a parser to treat `\0` as separators.

Comment: @Chinmay: The usual program execution system calls, at least in Unix (`execve` and its siblings) and Windows (`CreateProcess`), all trim strings off at NUL. So, that's at the OS level, not just library. :-)