# C programming give \0 as argument

Tags: c, bash

I am trying to test a program, people should not be able to put any character as the first argument, it is done this way :

```
   for (i=0; argv[1][i]!=0; i++) {
        if (argv[1][i] > 'z' || argv[1][i] < 'a') {
             printf("Not allowed char in filename\n");
             exit(1);
        }
    }
```

I was wondering if it was possible to fake a \0 at the beginning to introduce characters anyway, simply because after that the program copies the entire buffer (with strncpy on the whole chain) so it does copy what is after a \0 char.
My question is with bash, how can i write the first arguement to fake this \0 and then put a valid char which wouldn't be detected.

EDIT : so my goal is to do a simple buffer overflow with a shellcode like this :

```
\x6a\x31\x58\x99\xcd\x80\x89\xc3\x89\xc1\x6a\x46\x58\xcd\x80\xb0\x0b\x52\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x89\xd1\xcd\x80
```

Thanks to the answers I managed including \0 at the start of the character chain with `$printf("\0 abc)`
But still if i replace abc with my code, it detects actual characters in it. Not sure what is going on but I am trying printf without the program.

EDIT2 : Actually printf returns an error with the shellcode that is why the program detects a character. I am trying to solve the error, it seems bash is trying to interpret the shellcode in itself because of the $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bash's printf command

e.g.

```
yourcommand $(printf "\0abc")
```

Comment: thanks it works but i am still having issues with the characters i have after the \0. bash tries to interpret the resulting character chain before passing it to the program, therefore bash returns an error to the program... Any idea?

Comment: I was not aware of that issue, but it is perfectly understandable and I found the right explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283335/how-to-pass-in-a-null-character-in-a-command-line-argument-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Use `$'<letters>\<escape><letters>'` syntax (supported in bash).

I.e.

```
myaut@zenbook:~$ echo aaa $'bb\0bad' ccc
aaa bb ccc
```